# apps directory for symfony missing

Tags: php, symfony1

I got this error when following [this tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_2/en/03-Sandbox).

> Warning: require_once(...\sf_sandbox\apps\frontend\config\config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...\sf_sandbox\web\index.php on line 8

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure quite why you get the error, but from my (slightly limited) knowledge of french, I think thats quite an old guide. Would suggest you try the jobeet tutorial instead:

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/

Chapter one will leave you with a working symfony install thats good for any project (i generally follow this approach whenever i start a project) - not just the jobeet one. If you are new to symfony, the tutorial is a really good way to get a solid overview of the framework and leaves you ready to do your first project without falling down at every hurdle.

Comment: You're right it was too old, I downloaded the english version and it did contain apps folder :)

Answer (score 0):

check that the config.php file is actually there ...